# Magento Pizza Product - Using Advanced Custom Options vs. Configurable Product

Tags: php, magento

I've been struggling to find a final solution for having Pizza products shown on my website.

Basically, the large pizza can have 1-3 toppings, can have extra cheese and the toppings have different prices. Also, let's say a topping costs USD 3 and other costs USD 5, it should use the highest value, not sum them up.

I started build the pizza using [Advanced Product Options,](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html&ei=CWo1U_DPDfSmsATLlIGwAw&usg=AFQjCNHpL1-ju3DLcidEZ2QUxKWRl56XXw&bvm=bv.63808443,d.cWc) but I haven´t find a solution when there are multiple options with different prices.

So, I tried to play with the Configurable Products, with 1 attribute with 3 options, topping 1, 2 and 3. However, I cannot make a topping to show on all these 3 options.
This way, I would have to create all the toppings as simple products 3x, to make them appear, which is a pain in the ass for maintenance.

Could you please share some light?

I'm thinking that I may have to create 3 attributes, each with one option, but I would like to hear from you if somebody has ever faced this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set the pizza up as a bundle product, probably one bundle for each pizza size.

You will need experiment with the toppings but I think 'cheaper toppings are free' is not a standard Magento situation so you may have to edit the bundle code or experiment with shopping cart rules.

As a plan B, you could code all the logic into Javascript and when the user has decided all the pizza items then you could POST back to Magento the specific things to add to the cart.

But at the end of the day it might just be easier to create all the combinations in advance as simple products. I think that is what is [happening here](http://www.itoris.com/magento-design-pizza-store.html).